# How to switch to this package vendor?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I want to switch over to this patch vendor:

- https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/ppa

It promises a "better" font rendering with infinality, so I'd like to know how do I set up my freetype and cairo to be updated from his PPA.

Comment: no one knows how to change package vendor in APT?

Comment: OK I've managed to do that with Synaptic's "Force Version" feature (Ctrl+E)

Comment: they look a bit better now, btw. However I need to do some configuration

Comment: It's been only an hour since you asked, and your first comment was posted 2 **minutes** after asking the question. Have some patience.

Comment: -1 for being inpatient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the PPA, then did force versions of the binary packages (they are 7-10 for cairo and freetype) through Synaptic.

However, Sathya's solution would work also, since PPA's got higher priority than Ubuntu official repos. You just have to `apt install ...` the binaries, not `cairo`/`freetype` cause there are no such packages (they are source packages).

One thing is to be said - there is no established way to change vendor for a particular package in APT. Zypp of OpenSuSe's got that.

Answer (score 4):

Add the ppa to apt

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
```

Refresh the packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the packages

```
sudo apt-get install cairo
sudo apt-get install freetype
```

Run the scripts;

```
fontconfig-infinality
infinality-settings.sh
```

The last 2 may require root privs, if so prefix with `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to do it:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo-gobject2 cairo-perf-utils libcairo2 freetype2-demos
```